# how to inject storybook with Environment Variables

Tags: variables, environment, storybook

```
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook ",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sambego/storybook-styles": "^1.0.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addon-info": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addon-notes": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/addons": "^4.1.7",
        "@storybook/react": "^4.1.7",
        "autoprefixer": "7.1.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
        "eslint": "4.10.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
        "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "less": "^2.7.2",
        "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
        "react-styleguidist": "^5.5.7",
        "react-svg": "^6.0.21",
        "react-svg-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "storybook-addon-jsx": "^6.0.0",
        "storybook-readme": "^4.0.5",
        "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
        "webpack": "^4.29.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react-app"
        ]
    },
}`
```

this is my package.json ,i use `'STORYBOOK_THEME=red STORYBOOK_DATA_KEY=12345 npm run storybook'` cmd,but it didn't work. this is storybook official [website](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/env-vars/) to explain the using of Environment Variables.,did i use it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

Storybook will not pull in env variables that do not start with STORYBOOK_

To workaround this you can do a 1:1 mapping of your existing env variables in .storybook/main as part of your configuration object.

```
env: (config) => ({
    ...config,
    REACT_ENV_VARIABLE: process.env.REACT_ENV_VARIABLE,
    OTHER_VARIABLE: process.env.OTHER_VARIABLE,
  }),
```

This will allow you to use these env variables inside stories like you would inside the rest of your code through the standard `process.env.REACT_ENV_VARIABLE`

Related documentation https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/environment-variables

Comment: @jayarjo this answer should help, you map existing env variables or declare new ones using the same format.

Comment: process.env is not accessible in things like preview.js I guess

Comment: Using `process.env.REACT_ENV_VARIABLE` inside a story will net you a `process is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

this Q has been figured out.I'm using windows system,i have to input 'set STORYBOOK_THEME=red 'to set the Environment Variables,and then i can get this var by 'process.env.STORYBOOK_THEME'.

i changed the script as follow:

```
    "scripts": {
    "book": "set STORYBOOK_THEME=red&&start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook"
  }
```

it works!

Comment: What if one wants to inject contents of regular `.env` file?

Comment: @jayarjo As we say, crickets.

Comment: @vincent please see my answer for an example